# How can I learn more about this equation?

Tags: fft, transfer-function, ifft

I have come across an undocumented slide detailing the system response based on a time vs amplitude input signal.

The transfer function $$G(jw)$$ and $$w_{n} = 2\pi f_{n} $$

$$h(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(w_{k}) \left[\cos(\psi (w_{k})) \cos(w_{k}  t)- \sin(\psi (w_{k})) \sin(w_{k} t) \right]$$

Does anyone recognise this equation and can I obtain more info on its background?

Comment: It's the attempt to spell out the complex arithmetics of a discrete inverse Fourier transform of a sampled frequency response with amplitude $A$ and phase $\psi$. The result is supposed to be the impulse response of the system, but it's wrong because you get a periodic sequence and potential temporal aliasing. I'd ignore that undocumented slide if I were you.

Comment: Could you set me in the right direciton regarding the correct expression? I am looking to get the response based on time history data as input from test data and transfer functions as input obtained from FEM calculations.

Comment: Are you sure this is typed correctly?  There appears to be $j$ missing and the second term has the one $\sin$ inside the other.

Comment: @Hilmar, my bad. I have it corrected. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a continuous-time LTI system with an input defined as

$$ x(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{j \omega_k t} \tag{1} $$

then given the frequency response, $G(j\omega)$, of the system expressed as :

$$ G(j \omega) = A(\omega) e^{j \psi(\omega) } \tag{2}$$

then the output will be

$$ y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} G(j\omega_k) e^{j \omega_k t} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(\omega_k) e^{ j\psi( \omega_k)} e^{j \omega_k t} \tag{3} $$

Now if you further define an $h(t) = \mathcal{Re}\{ y(t) \} $, then you will have:

$$h(t) = \mathcal{Re} \{ \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(\omega_k) e^{ j\psi( \omega_k)} e^{j \omega_k t} \} \tag{4} $$

$$h(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(\omega_k) \mathcal{Re} \{ e^{ j (\psi( \omega_k)+ \omega_k t )} \} \tag{5} $$

$$h(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(\omega_k) \cos(\psi( \omega_k)+ \omega_k t) \tag{6} $$

$$h(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A(\omega_k) [\cos(\psi( \omega_k) ) \cos(\omega_k t) - \sin(\psi( \omega_k) ) \sin(\omega_k t) ]\tag{7} $$

Note that there can be different persectives into reaching the same result, hence this is just one possible interpretation. Furthermore, it's not clear why $x(t)$ or $h(t)$ should be defined that way, or even not clear if they really are defined that way or not... I think you can answer this by yourself, looking at your slides. It must have been clarified there.

Comment: Many thanks for shedding light on this. I don t know why h(t) is cast in this way. I  am trying to figure out what a piece of software is doing so that I can do it myself. Its not well documented.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to convert test data in the form of a time history, combine it with the fransfer function G (comes from FEM Simulation) to get h(t). Currently I am not sure how to do this. I presume I have to get the fft of the signal? Also I don t know what would psi(w_k) would be from the time history signal

Comment: there are too many unknowns in your problem. I guess you should find a beter documents which clearly describes what it does to its data, at best I can suggest...

Comment: What specific topic does the above equation fall under?